# Enqueue stylesheet from file

Tags: css, wordpress, templates

I'm wondering if it's possible to enqueue stylesheet from a file that's included within the page template. So for example I want to include a file that has a specific element and only want to load specific stylesheet when this element is loaded on page. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about checking if this element is loaded and if yes enqueing your stylesheet?

First, register the style with

```php
wp_register_style( 'my-custom-style', 'path-to-my-style');
```

This prepares the style but does not load them.

P.S.: There is a pretty nice wrap up about `wp_register_*` and `wp_enqueue_*` [here on SO](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/124354/why-wp-register-style-is-important-while-im-using-a-complete-wp-enqueue-style).

Second, you check if you are on the page with your custom element and there you actually load the script.

```php
if($elementLoaded === true) {
    wp_enqueue_style('my-custom-style');
}
```